# Print local file on server printer using ssh

Tags: ssh, printing

How can I print a file, stored on my local machine, on a printer I can print on via `ssh lp -d`?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `CUPS`?

Comment: yes, i'm on a Mac OS machine using terminal to ssh to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to provide the file via *stdin*

```
ssh remotehost lp -d < file
```

If you're not using `lp`, you'll need to use the appropriate command (`lpr -P ...`, etc.)